# Lattice points in a square pairwise-separated by integer distances

Tags: discrete-geometry, rational-points

Let $S_n$ be an $n \times n$ square of lattice points in $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

> ***Q1***. What is the largest subset $A(n)$ of lattice points in $S_n$ that have the
>   property that every pair of points in $A(n)$ are separated by
>   an integer Euclidean distance?

Is it simply that $|A(n)| = n$?
And similarly in $\mathbb{Z}^d$ for $d>2$?

---

[image: 5x5]

          

<sup>$5 \times 5$ lattice square, $5$ collinear points.</sup>

---

> ***Q2***. What is the largest subset $B(n)$ of lattice points in $S_n$,
>   *not all collinear*, that have the
>   property that every pair of points in $B(n)$ are separated by
>   an integer Euclidean distance?

---

[image: 3-4-5]

          

<sup>$5 \times 5$ lattice square, $4$ noncollinear points.</sup>

---

A $9 \times 9$ example with $5$ noncollinear points,
also based on $3{-}4{-}5$ right triangles, 
is illustrated in the Wikipedia article
[Erdős–Diophantine graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Diophantine_graph).

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{x\cdot x}$ is rational if and only if it’s integral, so you may as well ask for integer distances.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: Thanks! Revised rational$\rightarrow$integer.

Comment: I believe the current record for points in the plane, no three in a line, no four on a circle, all distances integral, is seven, as in Tobias Kreisel and Sascha Kurz, There are integral heptagons, no three points on a line, no four on a circle, Discrete Comput. Geom. 39 (2008), no. 4, 786–790, MR2413160 (2009d:52021)

Comment: The Kreisel & Kurz paper is available at http://www.wm-archive.uni-bayreuth.de/fileadmin/Sascha/Publikationen2/rare.pdf

Comment: If $d=25$, then in $S(2)$, the four points: the origin: $e_1+....+e_9$, $e_{10}+....+e_{25}$ and $e_1+....+e_{25}$ are each separated by integer distances

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks for that reference. I wonder if there is a difference between not-all-collinear and general position (no three in a line, no four on a circle)?

Comment: There should be 16 1’s... (starting at 10 and ending at 25).

Answer (score 6):

Denote by $f(n)$ the maximal size $|A|$ of a subset $A\subset 
\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}^2$ with integer distances. We have $f(n)\leqslant 2f(\lceil n/2\rceil )$, $f(n)\leqslant 3f(\lceil n/3\rceil)$.

This follows from the following observation. $A$ can not contain two points $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ such that both $a-c$ and $b-d$ are odd, or both are not divisible by 3. Therefore either all abscissas of points of $A$ have the same parity (respectively, remainder modulo 3), or all ordinates. Hence $A$ is covered by two translates of $(2\mathbb{Z})\times (2\mathbb{Z})$ and by three translates of $(3\mathbb{Z})\times (3\mathbb{Z})$. This leads to above estimates.

This gives $f(n)\leqslant n$ for all $n$ of the form, say, $n=2^k3^m$ (or $n=5\cdot 2^k 3^m$ as $f(5)=5$.) Since the ratio of two consecutive numbers of this form tends to 1, we get $f(n)=n+o(n)$ for sure.

Answer (score 5):

It is a theorem of Solymosi

*Solymosi, József*, [**Note on integral distances**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00454-003-0014-7), Discrete Comput. Geom. 30, No. 2, 337-342 (2003). [ZBL1047.52011](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1047.52011).

(Theorem 2) that the diameter of a set of $n$ integral points in the plane is at least $c n.$ So, the trivial estimate you mention is within a constant factor of optimal.

Comment: Within a factor it is obvious: any diagonal $y-x=C$ may contain at most 1 point.

Comment: With that observation one has 3n/2 as an easy upper bound. Care to post that observation, @Fedor?  Gerhard "Wish I Had Observed That" Paseman, 2018.10.13.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Your observation is correct for *lattice* points, but Solymosi's result is for any point set with integral distances (as in the OP's Q2).

Comment: @IgorRivin in Q2 they are also lattice points.

Comment: @FedorPetrov You are right. Anyway, the reason for the nontriviality of Solumosi's result is that he does not assume lattice points.

Answer (score 3):

@FedorPetrov's idea leads in fact to the solution of **Q1**. It seems that it may also provide some progress for **Q2**, but this is beyond this answer.

I denote $[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$; with standard conventions, we have $2[n]=\{2,4,\dots,2n\}$ and $2[n]-1=\{1,3,5,\dots,2n-1\}$. Let $A$ be a subset in $[n]^2$ with integer pairwise distances. We show by the induction on $n$ that

> (1) $|A|\leq n$, and (2) if $|A|=n$, then $A$ is collinear in a line parallel to a coordinate axis.

The base cases $n=1,2$ are clear. For the step, we use Fedor's observation that no two points in $A$ have opposite parities of abscissas and oppositve parities of ordinates. So we may assume all ordinates are odd. Now $A=A_0\sqcup A_1$, where the abscissas of the points in $A_0$ are even, and those for $A_1$ are odd.

Set $k=\lceil n/2\rceil\geq 2$. If $|A_0|, |A_1|\leq k-1$, then $|A|<n$, and we are done. Assume that, say, $|A_0|\geq k$. This means, by the induction hypothesis, that $A_0$ consists of all points with appropriate coordinates lying on some line $\ell$.

Assume that $A_1$ contains a point $x$ outside $\ell$.  Then $A_0$ contains a $y$ such that both projections of the segment $xy$ onto the coordinate axes are segments of nonzero length, and one of those lengths is either $1$ or $2$. But there are no Pythagorean triples containing either $1$ or $2$ --- a contradiction.

Hence $A$ is collinear on $\ell$, and $|A|\leq n$, as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Here are @AnthonyQuas's four points $\{o,p_1,p_2,p_3\}$ in 
$S(2) \subset \mathbb{Z}^{25}$:
$$
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc
   ccccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
   & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
   & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
   & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
   & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
   & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
   & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
$$
You can see that $p_1$ has nine $1$'s in its coordinate representation, 
$p_2$ has sixteen $1$'s,
and $p_3$ has twenty-five $1$'s:
$3{-}4{-}5$ triangles again—very clever!